# Where to initialize the base class of my app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class named `Home` which is the parent class of my app. Now, I want to initialize this class somewhere so that I can access everything inside the class from wherever I want. The starting point of the app is `RootViewController`. Should I initialize the app in the starting point? If yes, how should I do it so that it can be accessed from everywhere in the app?

Comment: I would probably have it as a property on AppDelegate and initialize it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Then to access it, use UIApplication.sharedApplication().myHome if you named the property "myHome" for example.

Comment: It would be great if you could give an example.

Comment: Hi, in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I added myclass = Home() and declared it as var myClass: myclass? in AppDelegate. Then when I tried to access it as UIApplication.sharedApplication().myclass from RootViewController, I am not able to access it.

Comment: Sorry, it was an incomplete solution. You have to access the delegate property of sharedApplication, and then access myHome from the delegate. I gave a complete working example in the answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per my comment above, set a property on the AppDelegate class with the type Home, initialize it in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Now you can access this instance of home through the sharedApplication.delegate.

In AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var myHome: Home?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.myHome = Home()

        return true
    }
```

Then access it in some other class:

```
let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var home = delegate.myHome
```