# Where to Initialize Subsystems in Swift Apps

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I have some subsystems that I need to initialize in my swift app. Unfortunately the View Controllers are initialized before the AppDelegate. Where can I put code that only needs to be run once on startup?

I tried application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) but it is called after my ViewController init.

The issue occurs when trying to debug ViewControllers quickly but setting them as the initial view controller.

Repro steps:
Put a breakpoints on the two *'d lines below.
MyTableViewController.init is hit before AppDelegate .didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
***     print("init coder style")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

... AppDelegate ...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
***     UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app/about_the_app_launch_sequence

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760621/where-to-initialize-the-base-class-of-my-app-in-swift

Comment: It gets called after the init function in my initial ViewController. I will edit my question.

Comment: "but it is called after my ViewController init" it should **NOT**... btw, could you elaborate what's the meaning of "ViewController init"?! `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` should get executed before even any view controller in the app get initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I have added some detail to my original question that shows exactly what's happening.

Comment: @ohthepain: I've updated my answer to include a solution to what I think your problem is.

Comment: @ohthepain: Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I added a LaunchScreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put this in the `AppDelegate`. You can use the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` function for this.

If you have a lot to set up you might want to create a separate "Coordinator" class for this instead of cluttering the `AppDelegate`.

**Usage with UIMainStoryboardFile in Info.plist**

If you have the `UIMainStoryboardFile` key set in your `Info.plist`, the main storyboard will automatically be loaded by the AppDelegate. This will then initialise the initial view controller, before `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is called.

The solution for this is to remove the `UIMainStoryboardFile` key, and manually load the storyboard as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Do your setup here

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  guard let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() else {
    fatalError("No intitial view controller configured in Main.storyboard")
  }

  window.rootViewController = rootViewController
  window.makeKeyAndVisible()
  return true
}
```